# In logical languages, what is the relationship between subset relations and the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: semantics, lojban, loglan

I will use Lojban for this example, but any logical language with similar relations could be examined; this should be portable to other Loglans, at least.

[{cmima}](https://vlasisku.lojban.org/cmima) relates sets to their elements; it can be glossed as "is an element of" and represents [elementhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)). Note that {cmima} is a binary relation.

In contrast, [{steci}](https://vlasisku.lojban.org/steci) also relates sets and their elements, but it is a ternary relation. {steci} relates a set, one of its elements, and an [extensional property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality) of that element. Some definitions of {steci} imply that there is an entire subset of the given set which contains only the elements which have the given property.

Now, Lojban has the feature that some components of a relation may be omitted, deleted, ignored, or removed. If we remove the first place of {steci}, which relates extensional properties, then we are left with {cmima}. In this sense, if {steci} is defined as a primitive relation, along with removal of components, then {cmima} may be defined from {steci}.

With all of that background out of the way, **does {steci} imply the Axiom of Choice?** Suppose that we provide {steci} with a set and an element of that set. Then, the various extensional properties of that element are [choice functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function) which select the element (and possibly other elements) from the set. This looks like the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice)!

Comment: This is an old question within the Lojban community, and I'm curious about what the wider conlang community thinks. This can be moved to a more technical forum, I suppose, but I'm not sure which one would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

My guess: It doesn't.

Sketch argumentation: *{steci}* allows you to talk about choice functions, but it does not guarantee that the thing you are talking about is actually a well-defined choice function, think, e.g., of the smallest element of an open interval as subset of real numbers. In other words: You can formulate sentences in Lojban that aren't *true*. You can lie in Lojban (as well as in any other language), and you can utter things that aren't even lies but complete nonsense.

Comment: {steci} does really do what it says on the tin. I'm not asking about arbitrary Lojban utterances; I'm asking about the semantics of particular selbri. Suppose I had asked whether {mlatu} always refers to Felidae, and you replied that people can lie and say things like {mi mlatu} "I'm a cat;" that's not what I was trying to understand.

Comment: The fact that there is a three-valued predicate steci implemented in Lojban does not make any assumption that it can always be satisfied, as far as I can see. Therefore the pure existence of that predicate implies nothing about the Axiom of Choice (my point of view).

Comment: And, by the way, as far as I understand the math behind that, you don't need to invoke the Axiom of Choice when you have an explicit Choice Function, you need AoC only in the absence of that.